# Error when clicking on the app menu item Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

When I click on a menu item I get an error:

[image: A JavaScript error occurred in the main process]

How can I fix this?

Code:

Main.js

```js
const { Menu } = require('electron')
const { createNewFile } = require('./js/createNewFile.js')

const menu = [
{
    label: 'File',
    submenu: [
    {
        label: 'New',
        click: () => {
            createNewFile()
        },
    }
}];
```

createNewFile.js

```js
function createNewFile() {
    document.getElementById('newFileWindow').classList.remove('hiddenFileWindow')
}
module.exports = createNewFile
```

When using `console.log(...)` nothing works in the function either.

Could it be because I have a `node_modules` folder that is not read-only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a step, the [main process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-main-process) doesn't have access to your [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process)'s DOM. If you want to change something in the DOM from the menu, you need to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) and a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file to communicate between your processes. For example:

**renderer.js**

```js
window.electronAPI.createNewFile(() => {
  document.getElementById('newFileWindow').classList.remove('hiddenFileWindow');
});
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  createNewFile: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('newFileWindow', callback)
});
```

**main.js**

```js
const menu = [{
  label: 'File',
  submenu: [{
    label: 'New',
    // `mainWindow` is the window you created with `new BrowserWindow()`
    click: () => mainWindow.webContents.send('createNewFile')
  }]
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you block security precautions in your `webPreferences`? Try this:

```
webPreferences: {
  sandbox: false,
  nodeIntegration:true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  webSecurity: true,
}
```

Comment: Enabling `nodeIntegration`, and disabling `contextIsolation` and `sandbox` are [security risks](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security).

Comment: Yes,which is I implied.